# Vector calculus problem

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, cross-product, gradient-flows

I have to solve this:

$$[(\nabla \times \nabla)\cdot \nabla](x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$$

But I am really drowning in the sand..

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

We have a third ordered derivative acting on a quadratic term.

**SPOILER ALERT:  SCROLL OVER THE SHADED AREA TO REVEAL SOLUTION**

> Using a form of [Einstein's tensor notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) where summation is implied when indices are repeated, we have 
>  \begin{align}(\hat x_i\times \hat x_j)\cdot \hat x_k(\partial_i\partial_j\partial_k)(x_{\ell}^2)&=(\hat x_i\times \hat x_j)\cdot \hat x_k(\partial_i\partial_j)2x_{\ell}\delta_{k\ell}\\\\&=(\hat x_i\times \hat x_j)\cdot \hat x_k(\partial_i)2\delta_{j\ell}\delta_{k\ell}\\\\&=0\end{align}

Comment: I think he does not know tensorial calculus yet, lets take it easy.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi Thank you for the comment.  This is a hint.  And the hint is that we have a third ordered derivative acting on a purely quadratic term.  The solution is for the benefit of those who choose to reveal it by scrolling.  The tensor notation used in the solution should not be difficult to interpret, but I can add a bit more under your suggestions.

Comment: I didn't mark the negative signal to you. Nice you are comprehensive, and excellent approach doing all this calculation.

Comment: @leonardofranciscocavenaghi Thank you for the nice comment!  Very appreciative.  And a+1 for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question:
First of all we apply the gradient:
$$\nabla (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = (2x,2y,2z).$$
Then lets evaluate the vector $\nabla \times \nabla$. Using the cross product we get:
$\nabla \times \nabla = (\hat{i}\partial_x + \hat{j}\partial_y + \hat{k}\partial_z)\times (\hat{i}\partial_x + \hat{j}\partial_y + \hat{k}\partial_z) = \hat{k}\partial_{xy} - \hat{j}\partial_{xz} - \hat{k}\partial_{yx} + \hat{i}\partial_{yz} - \hat{j}\partial_{zx} -\hat{i}\partial_{zy} = \hat{i}(\partial_{yz} - \partial_{zy}) + \hat{j}(\partial_{zx} - \partial_{xz}) + \hat{k}(\partial_{xy} - \partial_{yx}).$
Then, making the inner product:
$$\hat{i}(\partial_{yz} - \partial_{zy}) + \hat{j}(\partial_{zx} - \partial_{xz}) + \hat{k}(\partial_{xy} - \partial_{yx}) \cdot (2x,2y,2z) = 0. $$